# SwfUpload returns HTTP error 502

Tags: swfupload

I am using SwfUploader. On a couple of test systems, the uploads work OK, on a thrird, it gets error 502.  Is that HTTP error 502 (bad response from gateway) or an swf error? Any tips for tracking this down?

Here is the output from it with the debug flag turned on:

WF DEBUG: ReturnUploadStart(): File accepted by startUpload event and readied for standard upload.  Starting upload to /php/upload.php for File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (OPEN): File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 4653056. Total: 47326876
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 6062080. Total: 47326876
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 16744448. Total: 47326876
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 24281088. Total: 47326876
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 33128448. Total: 47326876
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 42532864. Total: 47326876
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 47326876. Total: 47326876
**SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadError: HTTP ERROR : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. HTTP Status: 502.**
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadComplete : Upload cycle complete.
Error Code: HTTP Error, File name: junk.wmv, Message: 502

Comment: a 502 error could be something on the server side.  It usually means there was an error communicating between servers.  Check this out:  http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm.

This could also be a permissions error.  Your client account may not have credentials to upload.

Also, does this error happen for all files or just "junk.wmv"?  What if you try to upload a smaller file?

Comment: You said that you have three systems. Are they on different internet connections? A bit more information would help solve this problem. As jason highlighted, the 502 is a network issue. This could be on the client side or the server side. Do you get this error repeatedly on the third test system?

Comment: Is possible that your server sided script ran out of memory? I think this problem is not related with SwfUploader but with your server sided configuration. In case of PHP: The phpinfo() function shows the current reserved memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

It says HTTP Error with HTTP Status: 502. So it must be a HTTP Status Error generated on the server side.

Usually such errors are logged into some error log, check those. Or maybe there is additional output - but that is not so easy to examine. One way to do that is using a proxy like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - using that you should see the 502 response.